# ASP.NET MVC 4 and SignalR posibilites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, client-server, real-time, signalr

I have two MVC 4 web applications that can be considered as client and server apps.

Client app is classic shopping cart web application where registered users select products from various stores and order them online.

Server app is a store web application where store employees receive orders from registered users and accept or decline their orders.

So basically, each store has its account on server web app, and each customer has its account on client web app.

All orders should be made real-time so that store employees receive them in real time, without refreshing their website. On the other hand, each customer should get a real time response from the store after his order has been accepted or declined.

Do you suggest using SignalR to implement this functionality? Is it possible to have users (clients) send orders to specific stores (servers) and for stores to send response to the order customer (client)?

If not, what's your suggestion for the technology?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR will work in both cases, but requires the user to be logged in and have their browser open to receive notifications. You will still have to have some other form of notification (email, status page, etc) in case the browser window is closed.

Here's a cool [tutorial of a Shopping Cart implementation](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1146/building-a-shopping-cart-with-signalr-aspnet-web-api-and-knockoutjs) with SignalR and Knockout.

Comment: Cool! This is all within the same web app. I suppose there shouldn't be problem if cart and admin are separate web apps?